# Page width issues (HTML and CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want my navbar to take 100% of the width of a page, and I write all the CSS and HTML normally needed for that. But for some reason in my browser it always shows a sort of padding all around. And I didn't code that padding to be there. Anyone knows how to fix that?

I am trying to learn to web developed so I am doing some exercises of the Odin project. So there is one where you're supposed to make a Google search page and I noticed this right of the bat.

Well I use Atom as a text editor, and I upload everything to Github. I heard some browsers have a default CSS file, may that be the problem?

Github repositorie link: https://github.com/ZoukCo/google_search

Comment: If you post your code will be easier to help you. There are sites like CodePen or JSFiddle for that, place a sample of your code there so someone can have a look.

Comment: Please post your `HTML` and `CSS` here

Comment: The navbar div is already 100%, its children also are. Are you trying to make the image 100% width?

Comment: you probably forgot to reset the browser's default styling: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BODY tag automatically has margins.

To fix this add this code to CSS:

```
body{
margin:0; 
}
```

Comment: Also, sorry about the bad format of my answer, I am using my phone to answer this.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer mate

Comment: Sorry I am new to StackEnchange. I am still getting used.